# Remove user in array Struct program

Tags: c, struct

I'm working in a struct array program to make some simple user applications. Below is a compilable code, it is not the full code, but it shows that the function to remove a user is not working. I'm new to C and I am not sure about how to do this user remotion. I thought about something related to a null array, but it didn't work. The program asks to enter the name, so the user will be removed.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define max_users 50

    int num = 0; //variable to count the number of users

    typedef struct
    {
        char name[50];
        int age;
    }user;

    user number[max_users];
    user aux[max_users];

    user read_user()
    {
        user user;

        printf("\nEnter your name: ");
        scanf("%s", &(user.name));

        printf("\nEnter your age: ");
        scanf("%d",&(user.age));

        return user;

    }
    void printUser(user user)
    {
        printf("\n-----------------------\n");
        printf("\nName: %s", user.name);
        printf("\nAge: %d", user.age);
    }

    void enterUser()
    {
        number[num] = read_user();
        printUser(number[num]);
        num++;
    }

    void printAllUsers()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            printUser(number[i]);
        }
    }

    void performUserRemotion(char name[])
    {
        char null[50] = {"\0"};

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (strcmp(name, number[i].name) == 0)
            {
                strcpy(number[i].name, null);
                printf("\n*** User removed ***");
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n*** No user ***");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void removeUser()
    {
        char name_search[50];
        int i;

        printf("Enter the user to be removed: ");
        scanf("%s", &name_search);
        performUserRemotion(name_search);
    }

    int main()
    {
        int choice;

        while(1)
        {
            printf("\n\nRECORD: ");
            printf("\n1) Enter User");
            printf("\n2) Remove User");
            printf("\n3) Print all users");
            printf("\n4) Exit");

            printf("\n\nEnter the command >> ");
            scanf(" %d", &choice);

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    enterUser();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    removeUser();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printAllUsers(num);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf("\n*** Exit ***\n");
                    exit(0);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

In the function below I planned to remove all the information about the user, so when I enter 3) Print all users, the user removed does not appear anymore and the array is reduced by 1.

```
void performUserRemotion(char name[])
{
    char null[50] = {"\0"};

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (strcmp(name, number[i].name) == 0)
        {
            strcpy(number[i].name, null);
            printf("\n*** User removed ***");
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n*** No user ***");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Pictures A and B are the user's registrations. Picture C is when you enter the command to remove a user, in this case, I registered 'user' and 'name' and wanted 'user' to be removed, so when I enter 3) Print all users, the screen only shows 'name'.

[image]

The program still has some basic problems, such as it can't read a name with space, but I will work on it later. The main problem is that I can't perform the remotion of a user.

Comment: What exactly does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: Hello! This is a great beginner question. Your current C code has a user struct, which holds 50 bytes for the character array, and another sizeof(int) bytes. While there are things I can answer about the semantics of the C programming language, I think this is also a bit of a software design question. How do you want to quantify a user being removed? The idea of a "null array" is not really something you can do here. You can fill up the entire array with nulls, but there's probably an easier way to accomplish what you're trying to do. How about a boolean to indicate a user being active?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the input you use, the actual output or behavior you get and the expected output or behavior you would like to get. If it is not clear, explain what's wrong with the actual output.

Comment: @Bodo I have edited the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @mkrieger1  I have edited the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of removing a user is wrong, because when you print all users, you print the whole content of the array. So to remove a user, you must have somewhere `num = num - 1;`.

A simple way is to find the index of the user to remove, and then consistently erase every record with next one:

```
void performUserRemotion(char name[])
{
    char null[50] = { "\0" };
    int i;
    // find the name
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (strcmp(name, number[i].name) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i == num) {
        printf("\n*** No user ***");
    }
    else {
        // remove the user from the array
        for (; i < num - 1; i++) {
            memcpy(number + i, number + i + 1, sizeof(*number));
        }
        num -= 1;
        printf("\n*** User removed ***");
    }
}
```

You still have a number of minor problems like unused variables, so when everything will work, you should ask for a full review on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)